# Problem with jQuery slider in IE6  

Tags: jquery, drupal, slider, coda-slider

I'm developing a web site using drupal cms.
 
I have installed a module called slider module which is used to slide a page with 
sliding effect, it uses jquery.

But it doesn't work in internet explorer 6, it doesn't display anything and no sliding effect.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using the JQuery UI slider and it works just find in IE6:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

Is this the same one you're using?

Answer (score 0):

What version of drupal are you using?

Drupal 6 uses jquery 1.2 out of the box -- if you're using the latest version of the jquery UI code it will be 1.3 so you need to install jquery update module for drupal.

Also make sure you aren't loading jquery twice.

Comment: thanks  also one more suggestion  what may be problem of jquery in ie 6  how we can resolve this

Comment: Are you using a packed or minified version of jquery? Try your script with the development (non-compressed) version. There are sometimes problems reading compressed js in IE6.